# Springboot Jpa - How to update entity to mysql database

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I want to update the Employee entity, but it does't work, it just adds the entity to the table instead of updating it.

**The Controller**

```java
@PutMapping("updateEmployee/{id}")
public void updateEmployee(@PathVariable long id, @RequestBody Employee employee) {
        employeeService.updateEmployee(id, employee);
}
```

**The Service connected to the JpaRepository**

```
public void updateEmployee(long id, Employee employee) {
        employeeRepository.save(employee);
}
```

Comment: when updating an entity your `Employee model id`(which you about to save) should be same as the `primary key id` that will be in the table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set the Id of employee which is updating details before `save()`. Here you are not specifying a primary key on which you want to update the data which results in a new record.

```
public void updateEmployee(long id, Employee employee) {
        employee.setId(id);
        employeeRepository.save(employee);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The common practice to update an entity in Spring Data JPA (with Hibernate) is:

1. read entity,
2. update its properties,
3. close the transaction.

For example:

```java
@Service
public class EmployeeService {

    @Autowired private EmployeeRepo repo;

    @Transactional
    public Optional<Employee> update(long employeeId, Employee source) {
         return repo.findById(employeeId).map(target -> {
             target.setName(source.getName());
             // update other props...
             return target; 
         });
    }  
}
```

So when a transaction closes, Hibernate will automatically update the entity in the database - the `save` method call is unnecessary.